# Cloud virtual machines available for free for open source testing?

Tags: open-source, virtual-machine, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

Anyone know about places in the cloud where you can create (virtual) machines (like Amazon EC2) to use for your computing tasks - places that offer a number (at least 5-10) of free machines, if they are used for testing open source projects?

Im not looking for places hosting CI environments like Jenkins, Hudson, TeamCity etc. for free for open source projects. Im looking for a place where I can run some servers where I can setup the open source system itself in a clustered and distributed environment. Then drive a test against that clustered and distributed environment from an automated test (e.g. executed from a CI environment).

Answer (score 3):

I think that [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/)  may attend your requirements. Specially if you do not need to have an external port open apart from the http

Answer (score 3):

Would AWS Free tier work for you? I realise it's not really a cluster..
http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: I tried with EC2 machine but performance wises it's really slow.

Comment: Surely this is very application dependent?